# jQuery UI-dialog- setting Buttons dynamically and pass values to function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, events, jquery

I'm dynamically setting buttons to the jQuery UI dialog like below.

```
arrButton = {};
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < dialog_buttons.length; i++) {

    for (var key in dialog_buttons[i]) {
        arrButton[key] = {
            id: key,
            text: dialog_buttons[i][key],
            click: function () {
                test($('#' + key));
            }
        };
    }

}

function test(value) {
    if (value.selector == "#confirm") {
        confirmthis();
    }
    if (value.selector == "#cancel") {
        cancelthis();
    }
}
$("#" + div.id).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: arrButton
});
```

when the button clicked, the key will be the last value from the iteration. Let's say we have keys confirm and cancel then when the button is clicked, the key parameter will be cancel.

So when I click a button from the dialog, I want to know which button was pressed.

Please find the fiddle which duplicates the issue I described above.

http://jsfiddle.net/DOmEl/qNGEw/11/

This contains a nested dialog which in turn trigger when clicked either Yes Or No of first dialog.
When the second dialog appear, both button have no effect.

Comment: `.selector` is deprecated - don't use it to test which element was clicked!

Answer (score 0):

why you are not using *this* ?

```
click: function () {
      test($('#' + jQuery(this).attr('id')));
}
```

Comment: I tried it but not working. I think "this" will not work here since the button not created while executing the click event. Hence the event not fired.